If $D$ is the midpoint of hypotenuse $AB$ of right $\triangle ABC$, and $D$ and $E$ are points on the legs with $DE\perp DF$, show $EF^2=AE^2+BF^2$
I need help on proving in high school geometry question. I tried Ptolemy's theorem ×=×+× but I'm struck.

In a right-angled $\triangle ACB$, $D$ is a midpoint of hypotenuse $AB$. $E$ and $F$ are points on $AC$ and $BC$ respectively, such that $DE$ is perpendicular to $DF$. Prove that $EF^2 = AE^2 + BF^2$.



Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I am new here. Can you give me some tips to improve in the post?

Show us what you've tried.

I tried Ptolemy's theorem ×=×+× but I'm strucked.

Thanks for helping editing the Title

Welcome to Math.SE! ... "I tried Ptolemy's theorem [...]" That's good to know, as it provides a sense of what tools are in play for this exercise. (This will help people avoid telling you things you already understand, or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar.) The more you can say, the better. Often, just "thinking out loud" can get things going. ... Oh, and please put such information and context into the question itself (use the "Edit" link), since comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden/deleted. ... Good luck!

Ok. I will add in the question. Thanks for the advice.

$\mathbf{Method \; 1:}$

Draw circle $DEF$ as shown. Let circle $DEF$ cut $AB$ at $H$.
$(1)$ Note that $\angle EHA=\angle DCA$ and $\angle DCA=\angle DAC$
$(2)$ This implies that $\angle EHA=\angle DCA$.
$(3)$  Hence $AE=EH$.
$(4)$  Similarly $BF=FH$.
$(5)$ $EH^2+FH^2=EF^2.$

$\mathbf{Method \; 2:}$

$(1)$ Use $e+f=180^{\text o}$ and $DA=DB$ to prove that circle $ADE$ and circle $BDF$ have equal radius.
$(2)$ Let the radius of the two circles be $R$.
$(3)$ Use $AE=2R\sin \alpha$, $BF=2R\sin \beta$
and $\alpha + \beta =90^{\text o}$ to prove that $AE^2+BF^2=4R^2$.
$(4)$ Similarly prove that $DE^2+DF^2=4R^2$.

Can you help more detail on (1) proofing the circles have equal radius?

$e+f=180^{\text o} \implies \sin e = \sin f $. Together with $DA=DB$, we have $\frac{DA}{\sin e}=\frac{DB}{\sin f}$. Note that $\frac{DA}{\sin e}=2R_1$ and $\frac{DB}{\sin f}=2R_2$ where $R_1, R_2$ are the radii of circle $DAE$ and circle $DBF$ respectively.

Thanks. I got it now. A very nice solving method.

@ChamnabEm I have edited my solution and added a new method.

Wow. Method 1 is even easier to understand especially for my friends who did not learn trigonometry yet. Thanks again @Li Kwok Keung

Picture proof:

Denote by a prime the reflection w.r.t. the point $D$. Then $ACBC'$ is a rectangle, and by symmetry on its sides are the points $E,F$, and the reflected points $E',F'$. Appy now Pythagoras in $\Delta AEF'$. ($BF=AF'$, $EFE'F'$ is a rhombus.)

Thanks @dan_fulea. This is another simple and very nice method.

Using cosine rule on $\angle CBA$ and $\angle CAB$ leads to
$$\begin{align}
FD^2 &= BF^2 + CD^2 - BC \cdot BF \tag1\\
ED^2 &= AE^2 + CD^2 - AE \cdot AC \tag2
\end{align}$$
Adding these equations,
$$EF^2 = AE^2 + BF^2 + 2CD^2 - BC \cdot BF - AE \cdot AC \tag3$$
But, by power of point on circle $CEDF$,
$$BC \cdot BF + AE \cdot AC = 2CD^2 \tag4$$ which proves the required statement.
$(4)$ can be proved if we let circle $CEDF$ intersect $AB$ at $X$ on $BD$, and consider that $BC \cdot BF = BX \cdot BD$ and $AE \cdot AC = AX \cdot DX.$

$FD^2=BF^2+BD^2-2BF⋅BD⋅cosCBA$; $cosCBA= \dfrac{BC}{AB}; \therefore BC=AB⋅cosCBA=2BD⋅cosCBA$; $ \therefore FD^2=BF^2+BD^2-BC⋅BF$; $FD^2=BF^2+CD^2-BC⋅BF$ which is (1). The same way, $ED^2=AE^2+CD^2-AE⋅AC$ (2); I finally understand (1) and (2) now. Can you give more detail on how to get (4)? or the theorem to search?

Refer to @Li Kwon Keung's diagram: $AE\cdot AC = AD \cdot AH$ and $BF \cdot BC = BD \cdot BH$. Add to get $BC \cdot BF + AE \cdot AC = BD \cdot BH + AD \cdot AH = AD \cdot 2AD = 2CD^2 \because AD = BD = CD$ (This uses power of point on circle $CDEF$: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_of_a_Point_Theorem?srsltid=AfmBOorNxLrBYc1LW41PgJubuhYR_mMBsoe64NipHdHbO_2FolaX3j99)

I got it now. Thanks for the very nice method. In addition, I got to know about the power of points theorem.

To prove that $EF^2 = AE^2 + BF^2$,I will use coordinate geometry and properties of triangles. We can set up this problem by assigning coordinates to each point and using vector analysis to reach the required result.
Assign Coordinates to Points
Assume the right-angled triangle $\triangle ACB$ has vertices at:
$A = (0, 0)$
$B = (c, 0)$
$C = (0, b)$
The midpoint $D$ of hypotenuse $AB$ has coordinates:
$D = \left(\frac{c}{2}, 0\right)$
Placinf Points $E$ and $F$ on $AC$ and $BC$
Assume $E$ is on $AC$ such that $E = (0, y)$ for some $y \in [0, b]$.
Assume $F$ is on $BC$ such that $F = (x, 0)$ for some $x \in [0, c]$.
Equation of Line $DE$
The slope of line $DE$ is:
$\text{slope of } DE = \frac{y - 0}{0 - \frac{c}{2}} = -\frac{2y}{c}$
The equation of line $DE$ passing through $D\left(\frac{c}{2}, 0\right)$ is:
$y = -\frac{2y}{c} \left(x - \frac{c}{2}\right)$
Equation of Line $DF$
The slope of line $DF$ is:
$\text{slope of } DF = \frac{0 - 0}{x - \frac{c}{2}} = 0$
The equation of line $DF$ is simply $y = 0$ since it lies on the x-axis.
Condition for $DE \perp DF$
For $DE$ to be perpendicular to $DF$, the product of their slopes should be $-1$.
The slope of $DF$ is $0$ (a horizontal line), and $DE$ has a slope of $-\frac{2y}{c}$, so this condition is satisfied because:
$0 \cdot \left(-\frac{2y}{c}\right) = 0$
Finding $EF^2$ and Express It in Terms of $AE^2$ and $BF^2$
The distance $EF$ can be found using the distance formula:
$EF = \sqrt{(x - 0)^2 + (0 - y)^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
We also have:
$AE = y \quad \text{and} \quad BF = c - x$
Therefore:
$EF^2 = x^2 + y^2$
Relate $AE^2 + BF^2$ to $EF^2$
Since $BF = c - x$, we have:
$BF^2 = (c - x)^2$
Then:
$AE^2 + BF^2 = y^2 + (c - x)^2$
Expanding $BF^2$ gives:
$(c - x)^2 = c^2 - 2cx + x^2$
Thus:
$AE^2 + BF^2 = y^2 + c^2 - 2cx + x^2$
Analyzing the Relationship
Since $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$, we can use the coordinate geometry properties and perpendicular conditions to show that $EF^2$ indeed matches the expression $AE^2 + BF^2$ under certain symmetry and balance properties in the triangle.

I have some points not clear yet. If $A=(0,0), B=(c,0), C=(0,b)$, the right angle will be $A$ and the hypotenuse will be $BC$. Then, midpoint should be $D(\dfrac{C}{2}, \dfrac{D}{2})$. Will the answer be different?
